# Check if a file exist in appdata without adding the full path in the python code

Tags: python, file, path

How i can check if a file exist in appdata using a environment variable without adding the full path in the python code ?? i have added %APPDATA% but the code is not working with a environment variable

```html
import os

PATH = '%APPDATA%\\java.exe'
if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print("File exists and is readable")
else:
    print("Either the file is missing or not readable")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `os.path.expandvars`:

```
import os

PATH = os.path.expandvars('%APPDATA%\\java.exe')  # <- HERE
if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print("File exists and is readable")
else:
    print("Either the file is missing or not readable")
```

Answer (score 0):

`%%` is mostly used in windows and batch scripts.
This will be another way to do so, where you create the path till java.exe from the environmental variable APPDATA.

```
import os

PATH = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'java.exe')

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print("File exists and is readable")
else:
    print("Either the file is missing or not readable")
```